# Syntax for "RETURNING" clause in Mysql PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm trying to add a record, and at the same time return the id of that record added. I read it's possible to do it with a `RETURNING` clause.

```
$stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2) 
                               VALUES (:value1, :value2)
                          RETURNING id");
```

but the insertion fails when I add RETURNING. There is an `auto-incremented` field called `id` in the table being added to.

Can someone see anything wrong with my syntax? or maybe PDO does not support `RETURNING`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with PDO supporting it or not. `RETURNING` is supported by Oracle and PostgreSQL but not by MySQL.

Use [`PDO::lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) instead.

Comment: what about returning other variables other than the last insert id?