# Increment Column on Select

Tags: mysql, triggers

Evening,

I'm currently running this query:

```
SELECT `id`, `type`, `controller` FROM `urls` WHERE `url` = :url;
UPDATE `urls` SET `views` = `views` + 1 WHERE `url` = :url;
```

I run this when a page is loaded and it increments the views column by 1. However, I'm interested to know if there is a way (maybe using something like a trigger) that the view column could be incremented automatically.

Comment: AFAIK you are going to have to keep the queries separate. SELECT, then UPDATE. Pretty sure you can't UPDATE on SELECT.

Comment: When I run this query:
    SELECT `id`, `type`, `controller` FROM `urls` WHERE `url` = :url;

I'd like the view column of that table to be incremented by 1, as the UPDATE query does, but without having to run the update query.

In short:
* page load
* query urls database for page details
* on that query trigger the view column for the selected row to be incremented by 1

@Marcus Recck - The above query works for me.

Comment: Also, so you don't go blind early, get rid of all those unnecessary back-ticks; none of your terms are reserved words, so none of them need escaping with backticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find an exact duplicate but [Syntax for "RETURNING" clause in Mysql PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796244/syntax-for-returning-clause-in-mysql-pdo) and [Mysql returning clause equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583353/mysql-returning-clause-equivalent) give you the answer you need.

MySQL does not have an equivalent of Oracle and PostgreSQLs `returning into` clause. You'll have to use two separate statements.

---

If you're expecting to do a lot of updates it *might* (conditional, it might not) be better to keep the number of views in a separate table, especially as you're not returning the view count in your query. Something like the following:

```
insert into url_views values(url);

select `id`, `type`, `controller` from `urls` where `url` = :url;
```

and then if you need the number of views:

```
select count(*)
  from url_views
where url = :url
```

or use MySQLs [`insert ... select` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html).